# FileWriter date null value

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I have a date value that I want to write onto a file using

```
 fw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(root + "/log.txt"));

             fw.newLine();
             fw.write("," + "server timestamp   " + "," +  " Timestamp");
             fw.newLine();
             fw.write( " ,");
             fw.write(dateString + "," +  currentTimeStamp);
```

but everytime dateString and currentTimeStamp are null, via toast I can see that dateString and currentTimeStamp are not null, yet I cannot write them via FileWritter.

Here is the code for dateString

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH-mm-ss_SSS");


             dateString = formatter.format(returnTime);


                 currentTimeStamp = formatter.format(new Date());
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can't write them via `FileWriter`"? Generally after you write something you should always flush the streams, and from what you posted, you don't flush or close the stream.

Comment: When I write those Strings they come out as null.

Comment: I close the stream at the end of the operation, I can write all the data I want via FileWriter except those date strings.

Comment: Are you sure you are writing `dateString` and `currentTimeStamp` after they are initialized?

Comment: Yes, quite certain, via a toast I can see that the values have been initialized way before I write those values into a file.

Comment: Never mind, Josh M you were right, I made a mistake and those strings were not initialized yet.

Comment: Yeah I figured. Seems like the only possible reason to why they were coming out null. Glad I was able to help you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I runing your code

```
String dateString, currentTimeStamp;
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH-mm-ss_SSS");
Date returnTime = new Date();

dateString = formatter.format(returnTime);
currentTimeStamp = formatter.format(new Date());

BufferedWriter fw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("E:\\log.txt"));
fw.newLine();
fw.write("," + "server timestamp   " + "," + " Timestamp");
fw.newLine();
fw.write(" ,");
fw.write(dateString + "," + currentTimeStamp);
fw.flush();
fw.close();
```

and i get log.txt

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that you never define `returnTime`

Comment: dateString and currentTimeStamp are already Strings, I tried using the to.String but I get a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

The variables were not initialized correctly.